# Get all values related to id (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two tables Patients and appointments.

Here is model of patients

```
 public partial class Patient
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Patient()
    {
        this.Appointments = new HashSet<Appointment>();
        this.Patient_to_investigation = new HashSet<Patient_to_investigation>();
        this.Patient_to_appointment = new HashSet<Patient_to_appointment>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string Date_of_Birthday { get; set; }
    public string Adress { get; set; }
    public string Kind_of_medical_insurance { get; set; }
    public string Name_of_medical_insurance { get; set; }
    public string Patients_med_insurance { get; set; }
    public string Status_of_medical_insurance { get; set; }
    public string Index { get; set; }
    public string Country_code { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Refering_organization { get; set; }
    public string Refering_health_center { get; set; }
    public string Refering_doctor { get; set; }
    public string Refering_organization_adress { get; set; }
    public string Additional_fuse { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Last_edit { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Patient_to_investigation> Patient_to_investigation { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Patient_to_appointment> Patient_to_appointment { get; set; }
}
```

Here is Appointment model

```
 public partial class Appointment
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Appointment()
    {
        this.Patient_to_appointment = new HashSet<Patient_to_appointment>();
        this.Appointments_to_Doctors = new HashSet<Appointments_to_Doctors>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Start_appointment { get; set; }
    public string End_appointment { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Type_of_appointment { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Patient")]
    public Nullable<int> Patient_id { get; set; }
    public string Kasse { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }

    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Patient_to_appointment> Patient_to_appointment { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Appointments_to_Doctors> Appointments_to_Doctors { get; set; }
}
```

Also I have table to connect patient with appointments (because of one patient may have several appointments)

```
public partial class Patient_to_appointment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Patient_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Appointment_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Appointment_id")]
    public virtual Appointment Appointment { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Patient_id")]
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
}
```

In view I have button that on click get patients name and get id of this patient.

Here is code how I do this on back end

```
  var id = ctx.Patients.Where(x => x.Name == name).Select(x=> new
            {
                id = x.Id
            });
```

After this I need to get all appointments Title for this patient id.

How I need to write query correctly?

Comment: You don't need the `Patient_to_appointment` table because the appointment has the patient ID already. This means you only need to to `ctx.Appointments.Where(apt => apt.Patient_id == id)`

Comment: Your `Patient` class already contains `ICollection<Appointment> Appointments` (its not clear why your need `Patient_to_appointment`), so the collection of appointments will be populated when you get your Patient

Comment: okay. I understood this. But I have error. `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type '<anonymous type: int id>' to 'int?' RS_Main C:\Users\nemes\Source\Repos\RIS_Project_New\RS_Main\Controllers\PatientDatabaseController.cs 43 Active
` @DavidG

Comment: On which line of code is that?

Comment: `var items  = ctx.Appointments.Where(apt => apt.Patient_id = id)` @DavidG

Comment: What is `id` here?

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the code you have shown. How are you using your `var id` value?

Comment: `id` is `var id = ctx.Patients.Where(x => x.Name == name).Select(x=> new
                {
                    id = x.Id
                })` @DavidG

Comment: If you want `var id` to be an `int` then its `int id =  ctx.Patients.Where(x => x.Name == name).Id;` (do not create an anonymous object). But you do not need to call the database a 2nd time - you already have the `Patient` record

Comment: So you are trying to get a patient by name, what happens if two patients have the same name?

Comment: `Name` is First and last name of patient@DavidG

Comment: Yes, but people share names. I know several people with the exact same name as me...

Comment: That does not make it unique (I know 3 David Jones). Query your records by the `Id` property

Comment: Okay, so what is solution in this case?

Make hidden field on front end , where I will pass id?@DavidG

Comment: Yes, always pass around the ID or some unique identifier, for example a patient identifier.

Comment: Okay, thank's @DavidG

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the 'id' is going to be enumerable type.

So you could write

```
List<string> appointmentTitles = new List<string>();
foreach (int patientId in id)
{
    var patientAppointment = ctx.Appointments.Where(x => x.Patient_id == patientId);
    if (patientAppointment != null && patientAppointment.Any())
    {
    // note there can be multiple appointments
        foreach (var appointment from patientAppointment)
        {
            appointmentTitles.Add(appointment.Title)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will make multiple database requests, horribly inefficient.

Comment: As a side note, `if (patientAppointment != null && patientAppointment.Any())` is unnecessary (`patientAppointment` cannot be `null` - just an empty collection, and the loop wont execute if there are no items)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the error noted in the comments

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type '' to
>   'int?' RS_Main
>   C:\Users\nemes\Source\Repos\RIS_Project_New\R‌​S_Main\Controllers\P‌​atientDatabaseContro‌​ller.cs
>   43 Active

you need to **remove that new {}** inside the select:

```
 var id = ctx.Patients.Where(x => x.Name == name).Select(x=> x.Id);
```

with the new { ...}  you are returning an anonymous type and not the int.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
var patient = ctx.Patients.Include(a => a.Appointments).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == patientId);
```

This will give you the data of patient as well as its appointment which you can access in your view by iterating on appointments list (using patient.Appointments).